# can someone explain why the modulo function in this code isn't working?

Tags: c, cs50

So I am currently learning C with CS50 and I am currently doing the [greedy problem](http://docs.cs50.net/problems/greedy/greedy.html#staff-solution) from pset1, the purpose of this program is to output to the user, the least amount of coins that he will receive for the change that he's owed: for example if he's getting 32 cents of change back he will get 1 quarter, 1 nickel and 2 pennies for a total of 4 coins. I've been having quite a bit of trouble with counting the number of coins that he will receive, after using the modulo function to count the coins I keep getting the error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double') and I have no idea as to why, can someone clarify and/or possibly help me fix the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float coins;
    int quarters, dimes, nickles, pennies;

    // This part of the code prompts the user to input the amount of money that he's owed
    // making sure that the value entered is positive and bigger than 0 or else the 
    // program will reprompt the user for input
    do {
        printf("How much money are you owed?");
        coins = get_float();
    } while (coins <= 0.0);

    /* this is where the problem is, I'm trying to count the change given to the user with this
     formula but the compiler keeps telling me that there is something wrong with the modolo
     function that im using but im not sure what the problem is exactly */

    quarters = coins / 0.25;
    dimes = (coins % 0.25) / 0.10;
    nickles = ((coins % 0.25) % 0.10) / 0.05;
    pennies = ((coins % 0.25) % 0.10) % 0.05;

    int SumOfCoins = quarters + dimes + nickles + pennies;

    printf("%i\n", SumOfCoins);
}
```

Comment: `%` operator is defined for integers only.

Comment: The error message could not be clearer!

Comment: @EugeneSh. prefer "integral types" to "integers"?

Comment: @Bathsheba http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p2 *The operands of the % operator shall have integer type.*.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Let's not mislead folk. I've built an answer that verifies it works for `long`, where `long` is bigger than `int`. Perhaps I'm just an odd cat preferring to use "integral" to mean all whole-number types, and "integer" to mean just `int`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Apparently you are :) The standard is using "integer types" for both.

Comment: @Bathsheba: That's why we differentiate between integer and `int`. As a sidenote: integral types would also include BCD or other types which are not covered by "integer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is correct that fmod for floating point numbers, I am not sure why you want to consider coins to be a float in your code. The number of coins will always need to be an integer as you cannot have something like half a coin.

```
int main(void){
float dollars;
int cents;
int coins;

do{
    printf("O hai! How much change is owed?");
    dollars = get_float();
} while(dollars < 0);

cents = roundf(dollars * 100);

coins = cents / 25;
cents = cents % 25;

if (cents < 25){
    coins += (cents / 10);
    cents = cents % 10;
}

if (cents < 10){
    coins += (cents / 5);
    cents = cents % 5;
}

if (cents < 5){
    coins += (cents / 1);
    cents = cents % 1;
}

printf("%d\n", coins);
}
```

You can calculate the number of whole coins of each type by checking the denomination and decrementing the remainder while incrementing total coins accordingly.

Comment: The tests are redundant, so are the division and modulo `1`. Add the include files, indent your code and `return 0;` from `main()`.

Comment: The result of `int cents; ..... cents = cents % 25;` will _always be in the range [-24 ... 24]

Comment: BTW: `cents = roundf(dollars * 100);` is a good step.  Also consider `lround(dollars * 100.0)`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will take them into account to improve my code.

Comment: your answer is really interesting and I'd say the way you approached the problem is much simpler than my approach; in a good way! There's however a side case that you forgot to consider that with my limited knowledge is hard for me to fix, is there a way to have a validation rule on the user input that prevents adding numbers with more than 2 dp.?

Answer (score 1):

[The modulus operator ('%'), computes the remainder that results from performing integer division.](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)
 You need to use [fmod](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fmod.htm), defined in `<math.h>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `fmod`: `%` is only defined for integral types in C, with any arguments with types smaller than an `int` widened to an `int`.

(Out of interest, `%` is defined for floating point types in Java.)

---

For the avoidance of doubt, `%` is defined for types wider than `int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    long i = LONG_MAX - 1;
    long j = LONG_MAX;
    long k = i % j;
    printf("%ld", k);
    return 0;
}
```

See https://ideone.com/9Za4T9

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `%` operator with floating point values as it computes the remainder for the integer division. The floating point modulus function is `fmod()`, however it is not recommended to use floating point types to handle amounts in dollars and cents as their representation is not exact for many amounts, producing incorrect results.

You should instead carefully convert the amount to a whole number of cents and use integer arithmetic to compute the number of coins:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
    float amount;
    int cents, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies, coins;

    do {
        printf("How much money are you owed?");
        amount = get_float();
    } while (amount <= 0.0);

    // compute the number of cents with proper rounding
    cents = (int)(amount * 100 + 0.5);

    quarters = cents / 25;
    cents %= 25;
    dimes = cents / 10;
    cents %= 10;
    nickels = cents / 5;
    cents %= 5;
    pennies = cents;

    coins = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;

    printf("%d coins: %d quarter, %d dimes, %d nickels, %d pennies\n",
           coins, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
    return 0;
}
```